# Need to initialize a constant before gem initialization ( rails 3 and rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I am implementing a omniAuth authentication system through a gem and i would need to initialize a constant before the gem gets loaded.

Scenario:

The developer should write that constant in a config file, restart its server and that constant should be initialized before the gem gets loaded.

I tried to put it in a `config/initializers/omniauth.rb` file but i get a error when loading the server

```
unitialized constant OmniAuth::Strategies::Xyz::URL.
```

i am writting it in the gem in this manner:

```
OmniAuth::Strategies::Xyz::URL= "http://my_account.com"
```

Comment: i guess in this case you need to provide it in the boot.rb file before loading the gems

Comment: i really hope this is not the only option

Comment: try `before_initialize` doc here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initialization-events

Comment: @zipple really not sure about it but you can try once

Comment: hey @apneadiving, i tried that, still uninitialized

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a constant before gems are loaded in a Rails app, you can place it in `config/application.rb`, just before the `Bundler.require` statement. However, since no gems have been loaded yet, you might run into trouble setting such a deeply nested constant.

The proper way to do this, is not to rely on constants for configuration. Make a proper configuration object. You can make a [Railtie](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html) to add a proper configuration option to Rails itself and define the right hooks like `to_prepare` to start loading your gem's configuration at the right time.